# Dealing with XML parsing Scala

Tags: xml, scala

I am dealing with an online XML file containing empty fields :

```
<item/>
```

So when I use the Scala XML API function  .text :

```
(father \\ "item").text
```

My program just stops (no errors). How could I prevent my code from running in this problem ?

I could not find anything in the Scala API that worked for me (.isEmpty, equals(null)). Maybe a library could help me resolve this problem.

Comment: Which version of Scala / scala-xml are you using ? Here `(<item/> \\ "item").text` returns an empty string (`String = ""`)

Comment: `(father \\ "item").text.isEmpty` should work just great.

Comment: to me it returns <item/>. I am on version 2.10

Comment: @nattyddubbs that was it ! it's helps me discriminate between empty and full ones

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`(father \\ "item").text.isEmpty` should work just great.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably overkill, but if you deal with a lot of xml, I worked on a project that required extensive xml parsing. We ended up open sourcing the library we built, [Xtract](https://www.lucidchart.com/techblog/2016/07/12/introducing-xtract-a-new-xml-deserialization-library-for-scala/). It might be useful for future projects at least. For this solution, it'd look like this:

```
val emptyReader = (__ \\ "item").read[String].filter(text => !text.isEmpty)
```